# How to load a byte into an array in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I attempted to change an element of an array for a byte. But I am having trouble doing it.
The first part of the code is to access the element I want to change. In this case, is the first one. I prefer to not change this part of the code. However I'm pretty sure the mistake in doing is below the###

```
array   .word    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
l       .byte   'L'

firstletter:
    li  $t1,1       # save row num
    li  $t2,1       #save col num
    addiu   $t1,$t1,-1  #Normalize row number
    addiu   $t2,$t2,-1  #Normalize col #
    li  $t3,12      #size of row
    mul $t1,$t1,$t3 #get row offset
    li  $t3,4       #size of col
    mul $t2,$t2,$t3 #get col offset
    la  $s0,board
    add $s0,$s0,$t1 #add row offset to address of board
    add $s0,$s0,$t2 #add col offset to address of board
####Here where I think my mistake is.
    lb  $s4,l
    sb  $s4,0($s0)

    j   $ra
```

Comment: _"I am having trouble doing it"_ is not an adequate problem description. You need to detail what you're seeing, and what you expected to see. And you should also post all relevant code needed for reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax instead at the top:

`l:      .ascii  "L"`

and then try this at the bottom:

```
la      $s4, l
lb      $s0, 0($s4)
```

Your issue seems to be that you are loading the address of 'l' into s4 and not the actual value of 'l'.

Had to look at some code I wrote years ago, and that worked for me.  Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I cannot get it to work. When printing the array I'm still getting a 0 instead of an L

Comment: Ah well I'm not sure then.  Have you tried using the -d flag to debug?